What makes Raney Nickel so effective as a catalyst in alkaline fuel cells?
I've been reading extensively about alkaline fuel cells (AFC). One of the key points that has been highlighted is that AFCs can either use Raney Nickel or Platinum as a Catalyst. Wikipedia lists a number of other metals that can be used as catalysts at the anode of an AFC, but I have not found any substancial sources explaining which could be used as a cost-effective (and non-pyrophoric) alternative.
What makes Raney Nickel so effective as a catalyst in alkaline fuel cells?

Since you've referred to the Wikipedia article, which mentions large surface area and porosity, and describes its adsorption of H2; and also mentions nickel silicide as a non-pyrophoric alternative, what additional information are you seeking?

@DrMoishePippik I guess what I'm looking for is whether any nickel-based alloy with the same ratio (assuming there are only two elements) could be used. For example, could a copper nickel or Monel be effective catalysts?

Likely not anything. Again, referring to the article, Zn or Cr are promoters, but you could experiment (as did Raney).
